# How I can wait untill object exists to load html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my service after log in I am downloading from rest some data, and base on them I am display some tab or not. How can I load the HTML when data is already loaded? ngif at the begin of HTML does not work. I need  to refresh page to load correct tabs. Thanks in advance.
Best Regards

Comment: Could you share some code? It will give us a better idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use an Angular Route Resolver for this. Resolvers prevent the route being loaded until the data is loaded. A Guard is not the correct approach. A Guard is used to prevent access to a route based on some sync / async condition and not for pre-loading route data.